# "START /W" with additional switches

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, silent-install

I am trying to run a silent install of several exe's via a batch file, however need them to run one by one instead of simultaneously. It seems like "START /W" wont work when switches not native to it are used, for example:

```
START /WAIT "%userprofile%\desktop\jre-8u25-windows-i586.exe" /s
```

returns the following error:

> invalid switch "/s"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`start` has a weird syntax where the first string in quotes is the new (console) window title. Your command is quoted, so `start` interprets it as the title, and doesn't know what `/s` is.

So, add a dummy title, like this:

```
START /WAIT "" "%userprofile%\desktop\jre-8u25-windows-i586.exe" /s
```

Comment: Answered in no time flat. Thank you Jonathan, it worked